# Remove repeated(consecutive or non-consecutive) word in a String using regex

Tags: java, regex, duplicates

How do I remove duplicated/repeating words(both consecutive and non-consecutive), using regex in Java?

```
Hello to everyone hello in this world world \\ how do I convert this into

Hello to everyone in this world \\into this
```

I did find a regex which can find non-consecutive repeated words:

```
regex: (?s)(\b\w+\b)(?=.*\b\1\b)
```

So, how do I use this regex, to remove repeated words(and only keep the first occurrence of the duplicated word)?

Comment: [See this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicate-words-from-sentence-using-regular-expression/) or just use a HashSet instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
String text = "Hello to everyone hello in this world world \\ how do I convert this into";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(\\b\\w+\\b)(.*?) \\b\\1\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    text = m.replaceAll("$1$2");
    m = p.matcher(text);
}
```

[See Java Demo](https://ideone.com/goD3Ll)

Comment: @WJS, you are correct -- it does not get rid of non-consecutive words and I missed that. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @CodeHard It did not return the original string; it got rid of the second occurrence of `world`.

Comment: @Booboo Thanx!! It helped a lot.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here a non-regex approach using streams, assuming the words are separated by a space

```
String original = "Hello to everyone hello in this world world";
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
String modified = Arrays.stream(original.split(" ")).filter(s -> set.add(s.toLowerCase())).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative where you apply `replaceAll` twice with two different patterns. There are probably some subtleties I missed but this works for the supplied string.

```
String str =
        "how do do I remove how repeated words from this words sentence.";

String nonc = "(?i)(\\S+)(.*)(\\1(\\s|$))";
String conc = "(?i)(\\S+\\s)(\\1)";
str = str.replaceAll(nonc,"$1$2").replaceAll(conc, "$1");
System.out.println(str);
```

Prints

```
how do I remove repeated words from this sentence.
```